# Webapplication unable to run in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have a webapplication, made in ASP.NET 2.

This app runs without problems in IIS 6. When we upload it to an IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter) it runs in IIS, but when we open the site in a browser we get this error:

```
Server Error
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question, can you please add in the message from the Event Log on the server at the time you tried to run it in a browser

Comment: I cannot find any related events in the Event Viewer. Where should I look?

Comment: You should look in Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application, there will be a Error or Warning event which takes place at the time when you try and load the page in the browser.  This usually has a detailed stack trace or at least more information about what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I nedded to add a feature to the server. After I added `.NET Framework 3.5.1 Features` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that everything is set correctly in the ASP.NET tab, and also check under the Home Directory tab to make sure that the application has sufficient read/write and execute permissions.

Comment: When I try to access any of the section in the ASP.NET tab I get this error: The configuration section 'system.serviceModel' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Comment: Could this be the cause of your problem?